# How to implement ng-class to md-chip in angular-material

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

Here is my problem - i can't implement `ng-class='{activeTag: $chip.active}'` to `<md-chip></md-chip>`. I've been tried to add this directive to `<md-chips></md-chips>` but it doesn't works(because of `$chip` not in current scope). I also can add this `ng-class` to `md-chip-template` but visually it's not what i want, i need backlight for everything in tag. Btw, `<md-chip></md-chip>` dynamically created in `md-chips` directive. Maybe someone faced with this problem or just know the solution. Thanks.

**Here is my controller**

```
controller('ChipsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tags = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Pop',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Rock',
        active: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Reggie',
        active: false
      }
  ];

});
```

**My view**

```
<md-chips class="custom-chips selected" ng-model="tags" readonly="true">
<md-chip-template ng-class="{'activeTag': $chip.active}" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <a ui-sref="">
    <strong>{{$chip.id}}</strong>
    <em>({{$chip.name}})</em>
  </a>
</md-chip-template>
```

**My css**

```
.activeTag {
  background: rgba(85, 107, 47, 0.66) !important;
  color: white !important; 
}
```

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2lyKZtIadvuCkYF6S865?p=preview)

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3723

Comment: @mindparse yes, i saw this answer on github. But it's not the solution, i mean, how can i do this? This man just only added `ng-class` in generated dom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may prefer to use custom directive, which add special class to your `chip`

```
.directive('myChip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var myChip = elem.parent().parent();
            myChip.addClass('_active');

            scope.$watch(function(){
                return scope.$chip.active
            }, function(newVal){
                if (newVal) {
                  myChip.addClass('_active');
                } else {
                  myChip.removeClass('_active');
                }
            })

        }
    }
})
```

template

```
<md-chip-template ng-class="{'activeTag': $chip.active}" style="cursor: pointer;" my-chip>
```

styles

```
.md-chip._active {
  background: rgba(85, 107, 47, 0.66) !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vv2SvH1gNj3OIh1oaqvV?p=preview